# Can't seem to read UITextField value correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I am trying to verify that my uitextfield, which only allows numbers isn't 0 (zero). This check fails every time? When debugging resultingString = '0'( I type in zero ) as I am trying to make it fail, but it doesn't fail.

`NSString *resultingString = budgetField.text;`

```
if(resultingString == @"0" || [resultingString length] == 0){
    [AppHelpers showAlert:@"Dude!" withMessage:@"Don't be cheap I know you have more than a $1"]; //never gets in here.
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "==" for values, not strings:

```
 ([resultingString intValue] == 0 || [resultingString length] == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare two strings you would do this:

```
[string1 isEqualToString:string2]
```

Edit:
This would compare the actual strings and not the pointers to the strings.

Comment: +1 "==" in this case does a pointer comparison. Two "equal" strings do not have to point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator compares pointers. You want to compare the values of the strings instead, so use a method like `isEqualToString:`.